# Write UITableview'data into file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsdate

I want to write Tableview's data into file .In tableview I have three column. how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Data you are viewing in the Table must be coming from some Array or Dictionary.

Iterate through array or Dictionary to get each value of string (i suppose). Keep appending this values to an NSData. Then write this data to file using the method

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)useAuxiliaryFile;
```

Check this

```
 //For Array
    NSMutableArray *contentArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];//your array here
    NSMutableData *bodyData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    for (NSString *aStrData in contentArr) {
        [bodyData appendData:[aStrData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    }

    [bodyData writeToFile:FilePath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: how to write array into nsdata ?

Comment: It given me crash on         [bodyData appendData:[aStrData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

Comment: Check the debugger for error..Please put some error log to understand better

Answer (score 0):

How did you populate the table? Well, the same way (with a proper approach) will let you read table's data. As about writing content in a file, it's a different subject. Think.

Comment: I did not populate the table from any file.

Comment: Who said you did it FROM a file? You said you want the content of the tableview to go INTO a file